# How to control jQuery events when you have nested HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, events, event-handling

For example:

```
<ul>
<li>
   first element
   <ul>
    <li> second element
       <ul>
          <li> third element </li>
       </ul>
      </li>
   </ul>
</li>
</ul>

<script>
$('li').click( function() {
   alert('hello world!!!');
});
</script>
```

**The output is:**

THREE ALERTS WHEN I CLICK THE THIRD ELEMENT

TWO ALERTS WHEN I CLICK THE SECOND ELEMENT

ONE ALERT WHEN I CLICK THE FIRST ELEMENT

How to prevent with jQuery this?

What I'm needing is: **ONE ALERT FOR EACH CLICK IN ANY 'LI' ELEMENT.**

Comment: jQuery selectors works just as CSS selectors, all you need is specificity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `e.stopPropagation();`.

> **Description:** Prevents the event from bubbling up the DOM tree, preventing any parent handlers from being notified of the event.

```
$('li').on('click',function(e)
{
   e.stopPropagation();
   alert('hello world!!!');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

As you have nested `li` elements. The click handler applies to all `li` elements including the parent `li`'s.

You need to stop propagating the event bubble. So that once it execute the event handler, it does not goes up the DOM tree to trigger the same event.

```
$('li').click( function(e) {
   alert('hello world!!!');
   e.stopPropagation();
});
```